# c# sqliteHelper execute with 'or' can not get data

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm need to get data from sqlite with following sql.but always null. it's normal working on SQLite Expert tools, what's wrong with this ?

```
string sqll = "select id,name,intro from HDCP where phonenum='222222222222222222222222' or  qq='222222222222222222222222' or  busno='222222222222222222222222' or mailcode='222222222222222222222222'";
string result = string.Empty;
DataTable obj = sqliteHelper.ExecuteDataTable(sqll, null);
```

Comment: try to reduce condition and also enter logical data ...I think you might entered not equal number of 2

Comment: You need to share more information.. like what is `sqliteHelper`?

Comment: sqliteHelper  is an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

sqliteHelper  is an object instance. 
    sqliteHelper = new SQLiteDBHelper(Dbpath);

the sql is correct,and run well. but i had used wrong target db file with same name. thank you for